# Angular js With MVC 4.0

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project with AngularJS and MVC . So can anyone tell that should I create different JavaScript file for different controller.

My JavaScript files are:-

Modules
Controller
Services

Controllers are:-

Home controller
About controller
Contact controller
.
.
.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What version of Angular are you using? Show something that you did or tried

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have to read a couple of things first about angular. A very nice and easy tutorial [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00). Take the tutorial and then try to ask more specific questions.

It depends on what you want to accomplish but I think that you want to use MVC mostly for server related logic. In this case you can take a look at what ASP.NET Web API 2 might offer

> so can any one tell that should i create different different js file for different different controler

Regarding that have a look [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure), where you will find some angular directory best practices

Comment: sir jst want know that

Comment: for eaxmple we create  diffrent controller for diffrent page

Comment: similary diffrent diffrent angulas js file for diffrent diffrent page??

Comment: Well the whole point of angular is to create a single page application, which basically is (as the name states) one page with multiple sections that you can render/hide. Keeping that in mind you will have a controller for every section. This is a minimalistic explanation, there is much more to that and you should learn about creating reusable components.
Take the angular tutorial, you clearly need to learn the angular pattern first and then try to create an app